# Django Wagtail CMS migrate: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'app.CustomPage'>

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, wagtail

I have problem migrate simple app, bases on Wagtail CMS.

Traceback after runing `python manage.py migrate`:

```
  Rendering model states...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/yanik/oasis/oasis/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/yanik/oasis/oasis/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/yanik/oasis/oasis/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/yanik/oasis/oasis/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/yanik/oasis/oasis/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/yanik/oasis/oasis/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 100, in migrate
    state.apps  # Render all real_apps -- performance critical
  File "/home/yanik/oasis/oasis/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 60, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/yanik/oasis/oasis/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 166, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "/home/yanik/oasis/oasis/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 232, in __init__
    self.render_multiple(list(models.values()) + self.real_models)
  File "/home/yanik/oasis/oasis/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 270, in render_multiple
    "for more" % (new_unrendered_models, get_docs_version())
django.db.migrations.state.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'common.HomePage'>, <ModelState: 'news.NewsPage'>]
This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
 in an app with no migrations; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#dependencies for more
```

My Apps looks like this:

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'django_browserid', # Load after auth
    # Wagtail CMS
    'taggit',
    'compressor',
    'modelcluster',

    'wagtail.wagtailcore',
    'wagtail.wagtailadmin',
    'wagtail.wagtailsearch',
    'wagtail.wagtailimages',
    'wagtail.wagtaildocs',
    'wagtail.wagtailsnippets',
    'wagtail.wagtailusers',
    'wagtail.wagtailsites',
    'wagtail.wagtailembeds',
    'wagtail.wagtailredirects',
    'wagtail.wagtailforms',

    'wagtailforums',
)

PROJECT_APPS = (
    'common',
    'search',
    'ckanwrap',
    'news',
    #'forum'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + PROJECT_APPS
```

The only way i can make initial migrations work: remove PROJECT_APPS from INSTALLED_APPS, migrate. And after add PROJECT_APPS and migrate again.

But I have many other problems: cant run tests, cause same error appeared. Also if i modify my models and run `python manage.py makemigrations` i have `Nothing to migrate` but i change my models!

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have migrations for your `common` and `news` apps? If not, run `manage.py makemigrations common` and `manage.py makemigrations news`.

Comment: Thanks! My mistake. I was hoping manage.py makemigrations will create migrations for all apps in INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @knbk suggested I should create initial migrations specifically for each app! Since makemigrations  doesn't do it automatically.

In my case it was:

```
python manage.py makemigrations common

python manage.py makemigrations news
```

Comment: or better yet `python manage.py makemigrations {common,news}`